# CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of

Tags: entity-framework

I get the following error when I try to use my database context in the controller of my Asp.Net Core MVC application. What is my mistake Do I have to define "options"? And if so how do I do it?

> CS7036 No argument was specified that corresponds to the formal
>   parameter "options" of "DatabaseContext.DatabaseContext
>   (DbContextOptions )"

That's my DBContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace PlaudertischSoftware.Models
{
    public class DatenbankKontext : DbContext
    {
        public DatenbankKontext(DbContextOptions<DatenbankKontext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("PlaudertischSoftwareDatenbank");
        }
        public virtual DbSet<ObstSpielDaten> ObstSpielDaten { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AutoGaugeDaten> AutoGaugeDaten { get; set; }
    }
```

}